# Button accesskey has stopped working in IE11

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, internet-explorer-11

I have a button. It is 
 `<button type="button" id="btnOK" accesskey="s">Save</button>`

the script for button is

```
$(document).on("click","#btnOK",save);
```

It doesn't seem to work with accesskey now (just focuses the button)
On the other hand, if i use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

and either

```
$("#btnOK").click(save);
```

Or

```
$("#btnOK").on("click",save);
```

it works perfectly fine.

I've tried using the first code in  $(document).ready(function(){});, but it doesn't help, IE11 still does nothing.
Could anyone point me the issue ?
My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that IE 11 uses now PointerEvent instead of MouseEvent, but i can't get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your id in button tag.
instead of `id=""btnOK,` it should be `id="btnOK"`

BTW.. accesskeys are working fine in IE11

Comment: Oh, yeah, that was a typo here, on stackowerflow. Code i'm using is all right )
But the accesskey still doesn't work.
Btw, thanks for pointing out the typo )

Comment: Look at the actual rendered code in the Developer toolbar to see if type="button" has been moved to the end of the tag.